# Solving second order ODE oscillator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, mathematical-physics

I'm currently just taking my first ODE course and one of the questions is,

A projectile of mass $m$ is fired from the origin at speed $v_0$ and angle $\theta$. It is attached to the origin by a spring with spring constant

$k$ and relaxed length zero. Find $x(t)$ and $y(t)$.

Here's how I went about it:

$X$ direction:
$$m \ddot x = -kx$$
$$\ddot x = -\omega^2x$$
$$\omega = \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$$

---

$$x(t) = \frac{v_0}{w}\sin(\omega t)$$

$Y$-direction:
$$m \ddot y = -ky -mg$$
$$\ddot y = -\omega^2y - g$$
$$\dot v + \omega^2y = g$$

Then the integrating factor $=e^{w^2t}$

$$e^{w^2t}v = \int_{0}^{t} -ge^{w^2t}$$
$$v= -\frac{g}{w^2}$$

$$\dot y = -\frac{g}{w^2}$$
$$ y = -\frac{g}{w^2}t$$

Is this right way to go about this? Any help would greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Being an oscillator in both $x,y$, you're expected, from a physical point of view, to have some king of oscillating function for $x(t)$ and $y(t)$. The $x(t)$ is indeed right, but the $y(t)$ cannot: you got $y(t) = -\frac{g}{\omega^2}t$ which is the equation of a linear motion

Comment: @DavideMorgante I think I am struggling with the setup of the y function. Would you be able to point out where I am making a mistake?

Comment: You can try to set $u=-\omega^2y - g$, then you get $\ddot u = -\omega^2\ddot y$ and so you get the equation $-\frac1{\omega^2}\ddot u=u$ and so $\ddot u=-\omega^2u$

Comment: @Safder Sure I can! let me write a complete answer

Comment: @DavideMorgante Thank you.

Comment: @Holo I'll get it a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calculation for $x(t)$ beside some constants that popup after integration is good. Let us consider the initial condition $$x(0)=y(0)=0\;\;\;\;\dot{x}(0)=v_0\cos(\theta)\;\;\;\dot{y}(0)=v_0\sin(\theta)$$ so that at the start, the position of the projectile is the origin.

- Evaluating $x(t)$: yes, I said that your derivation is indeed good but I wanted to point out some thing because, as you're following you're fist course in ODE, you will encounter this concepts many times. You have this ODE to solve:
  $$\left\{\begin{matrix}m\ddot{x} = -kx\\x(0)=0\\\dot{x}(0)=v_{0x}\end{matrix}\right.$$
  As you said this is equivalent to $$\ddot{x} = -\omega^2 x$$ 
  $$x(t) = c_1\sin(\omega t)+c_2\cos(\omega t)\tag{1}$$
  Equation $(1)$ is the most *general* solution to the problem. The constant $c_1,c_2$ are to be found with the initial condition, mainly $$x(0) = c_2 = 0\\\dot{x}(0)=\omega c_1=\omega v_0\cos(\theta)$$ So the exact solution to the problem is, as you said $$x(t) = {v_0\over\omega}\cos(\theta)\sin(\omega t) = v_{0x}\sin(\omega t)$$
- Evaluating $y(t)$: in this case we have the following ODE:
  $$\left\{\begin{matrix}m\ddot{y} = -ky-mg\\y(0)=0\\\dot{y}(0)=v_{0y}\end{matrix}\right.$$
  You have to notice that the extra factor in this ODE, with respect to the other one, is just a constant (after dividing all by the mass) $g$. So you have two paths to take

  1. Solve the *homogeneous* equation an than the *particular* to have the solution as something like $$x(t)=x_h(t) + x_p(t)$$
  2. You can do a change of variables like $u = -\omega^2 y -g$ and solve the equation in $u$ to then come back to $y$.

I advice the second approach which gets you back to an ODE like the fist one that we solved. So let's begin: notice that $$y = \ddot{u} = -\omega^2 \ddot{y}\Rightarrow \ddot{y} = -\frac{1}{\omega^2}\ddot{u}\\u(0) = -\omega^2 y(0)-g = -g \\\dot{u}(0) = -\omega^2 \dot{y}(0) = -\omega^2 v_{0y}$$ Substitute in the ODE and you get 
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}\ddot{u} = -\omega^2 u\\u(0)=-g\\\dot{u}(0)=-\omega^2 v_{0y}\end{matrix}\right.$$ which has solution $$u(t)=c_1\cos(\omega t)+c_2\sin(\omega t)$$ Let us find the constants $$u(0) = c_1 = -g \\\dot{u}(0) = \omega c_2 = -\omega^2 v_{0y}$$
so $$u(t) = -g\cos(\omega t)-\omega v_{0y}\sin(\omega t)$$ From the definition we gave of $u(t)$ we can find the value of $y(t)$ $$y(t) = -\frac{u(t)}{\omega^2}-{g \over \omega^2} = {g\over\omega^2}\cos(\omega t)+{v_{0y}\over\omega}\sin(\omega t)-{g\over\omega^2}\\ = {g\over\omega^2}\left(\cos(\omega t)-1\right)+{v_{0y}\over\omega}\sin(\omega t)$$

In the end, the solution we get is the following $$\begin{align}\left\{\begin{matrix} x(t) = {v_0\over\omega}\cos(\theta)\sin(\omega t) \\y(t)={g\over\omega^2}\left(\cos(\omega t)-1\right)+{v_{0}\over\omega}\sin(\theta)\sin(\omega t)\end{matrix}\right.\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you for such an indepth reply. After reading through the change in variables section I finally understand it.

Comment: You're welcome, we're here to help! Note that the change of variable is a very useful in this type of situations where you want to go back to some forms that you can solve easily. Many times is simply done by setting the righthand side to zero and solving for the function $y*$, then you study the solution of the ODE for the function $y-y*$. Not that this is not always feasible, but for now you don't have to worry about it

Comment: @LutzL oops my bad! Correcting it now

Answer (score 2):

Your equations are correct, and as you can see, the two axis are independent.

In the $x$ direction, we have an ordinary harmonic oscillator, $x=a_x\cos\omega t+b_x\sin\omega t$. With the given initial conditions, $x=\dfrac{v_{0x}}\omega\sin\omega t$.

In the $y$ direction, we have a slightly modified oscillator

$$\ddot y=-\omega^2y-g$$ and we can simply shift the equilibrium point as follows

$$\ddot{\left(y+\frac g{\omega^2}\right)}=-\omega^2\left(y+\frac g{\omega^2}\right)$$

so that $y=a_y\cos\omega t+b_y\sin\omega t-\dfrac g{\omega^2}$.

More precisely $y=\dfrac g{\omega^2}(\cos\omega t-1)+\dfrac{v_{0y}}\omega\sin\omega t$.

We have two orthognal sinusoids with a phase difference, so that the trajectory is an ellipse centered on $\left(0,-\dfrac g{\omega^2}\right)$. It tangents a line at the origin in direction $\theta$.

[image]

Comment: @Isham: thanks. There could be more, I wasn't cautious.

Comment: +1 you're welcome Yves....

Answer (score 1):

The dynamics are given by

$$
m\ddot{\vec r} = -k\vec r + \vec w
$$

with

$$
\vec r = (x,y)\\
\vec w = (0,-m g)
$$

so we have

$$
m\ddot x + k x = 0\\
m\ddot y + k y - mg = 0
$$

solving with the initial conditions

$$
\dot {\vec r} = v_0(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)\\
\vec r_0 = (0,0)
$$

we get

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 x(t)& = & v_0\sqrt{\frac mk} \cos \theta \sin \left(\sqrt{\frac km}t \right) \\
 y(t)& = & \frac mk g \left(\cos \left(\sqrt{\frac km} t\right)-1\right)+\sqrt{\frac mk}v_0 \sin \left(\sqrt{\frac km} t\right) \sin (\theta ) \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

which gives the orbit

$$
g^2 m x^2 \sec ^2\theta+v_0^2 (y-x \tan\theta) (2 g m-k x \tan\theta+k y)
$$

Attached the orbit for $m=1, \theta=\pi/4, k = 1, v_0 = 50$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

$$\ddot y+ω^2y=−g$$ can also be written as 
$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2} (y-y_*)+ω^2(y-y_*)=0$$ where $y_*=-\frac{g}{ω^2}=-\frac{mg}k$. This is an oscillation in the shifted variable $y-y_*$ in the same way as in the $x$ direction. That is, the $y$ coordiate oscillates around the equilibrium level $y_*$.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the equation can be integrated in vector form.

$$\ddot{\vec r}+\omega^2 \vec r=\vec g$$

has the homogeneous solution

$$\vec r=\vec{c_c}\cos\omega t+\vec{c_s}\sin\omega t$$ and the particular solution $$\vec r=\vec g.$$

Now with the initial conditions,

$$\vec r_0=\vec{c_c}+\vec g=\vec 0,
\\\vec v_0=\omega\vec c_s$$ 
we have

$$\vec r=\vec g-\vec{g}\cos\omega t+\vec{v_0}\frac1{\omega}\sin\omega t.$$

This is an ellipse, inscribed in the parallelogram of vertices

$$\vec g\pm\vec g\pm \vec{v_0}\frac1{\omega}.$$